# Auto offset many dates in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a syllabus for my class that I wrote in Word. Part of that syllabus is a list of due dates for assignments. The assignments are due a fixed number of days after the start of the term. So one assignment is always due 7 days after the term starts, another 14 days after the terms start and so on. But I want to show the due dates as calendar date (eg. 10/15)

Is there any way to set up the document where I have one master date and the rest of the dates are calculated as an offset from that date? Every quarter I need to update the dates, it is fairly tedious and I always seem to miss a couple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to achieve via a field alone, but it's long and complex so probably not worth it. Instead you will need to use a macro. Both methods are described very well here on [Graham Mayor's webpage](http://www.gmayor.com/insert_a_date_other_than_today.htm)

Comment: As much as I dislike VB on principle, the macro solution looks like a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for your use, and you also have Excel, a fairly simple method is as follows. The details vary a bit depending on which version of Word you are using...

- Create an Excel workbook (let's call it c:\xl\assignmentdates.xlsx)
- In cell A1 (R1C1), put the base date
- In cell A2 (R2C1), put =$A$1+7
- In cell A3 (R3C1), put =$A$1+14
- etc.
- Optionally, put descriptions in column B.
- Save the file
- Select cell A1 and Edit->Copy
- In Word, click where you want the date and Paste->Paste Special,
  check the Paste Link button and select "Unformatted text", then click
  OK

You should either see the result, or a LINK field. If you don't see the LINK field, click alt-F9. It should look something like

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 C:\\xl\\assignmentdates.xlsx Sheet1!R1C1 \a \t }
```

- Copy that, paste in as many copies as you need dates in your
  document, and edit the "R1C1" to insert the correct dates in each
  case. Use Alt-F9 to toggle back to "field results" display.
- Select the document (ctrl-A) and press F9 to update the fields.

If you now modify the base date in the Excel file, all the dates should change in the Word file.

- Save both files.

After that what you should probably do when creating your documents is

- open the Excel file
- open the Word file and save it with a new name
- modify the Excel sheet
- wait for the updated dates to appear
- select the document and click ctrl-shift-F9 to "unlink" the fields,
  i.e. replace them by their results
- save and close both files

Personally, I would probably either use one of the approaches suggested by Adam, as they do not require a separate document, and I'd probably use the field code approach as it avoids VBA, but the field coding is a bit complex and you have to pay extra attention if you are using them multiple times.

There is one other non-VBA approach involving DATABASE fields that also relies on an external file, if you are interested.

Comment: I will look into the DATABASE field. The class already has a MySQL database that tracks assignments, if I can get Word connected with that, it could actually be fairly powerful I think.

Comment: FOr the DATABASE field, what I had in mind is that you create an Access .mdb (you can do it within Word by creating a new MailMerge datasource). Then set and display your base date using, e.g. { SET basedate "2013-10-02" }{ basedate \@"DD/MM/YYYY" } (alter the date format to suit your requirement). Then use a nested database field along the lines of { DATABASE \d "the .mdb path+name with doubled-up backslashes" \s "SELECT format(dateadd('d',7,cdate('{ basedate }')))" \@DD/MM/YYYY }. You have to use the final date format switch to remove a paragraph mark. There may be an equivalent for MySQL.